# ConcurrentUpdateException with single user

Tags: atg

On my Dev box running on single Jboss instance, I was able to see some occurrence of `ConcurrentUpdateException` on the Order item. Order repository uses Simple cache. I am trying to figure out a scenario how CUE could occur in a single instance. Also, a lock is obtained and order is updated in a transaction as recommended by ATG.

My assumption is that the lock would prevent concurrent request from updating Order at the same time. So, what could cause the order version in the database to be greater than one in the cache?

Comment: One or more of your updates are likely happening outside a transaction.

Comment: Correct. That's the reason I do a lock on the Order creator before starting a Transaction to update Order. Assuming that the locking works as expected - could there be any other reason?

Comment: Are you using the  following pattern? 1. lock on profile, 2. create transaction, 3. synchronize on order, 4. make your updates to the order, 5. Call orderManager.updateOrder( ), 6. End synchronize on order, 7. end transaction, 8. release profile lock

Comment: Yes. We are following exactly the same pattern. The only change is that in our case, since the same Order could be loaded and updated by multiple profiles (Supervisors/Approvers) we get lock on the Order creator and not on the current profile and I don't believe this could cause any issues.

Comment: Remember that other processes can also be updating the order e.g. scenarios etc.  Also, if you are using JMS messaging and connecting to a database which is shared you could be processing order updates from other servers etc.